# Write a bash code to replace strings in one file according to another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list like this

```
G1 John
G2 Jack
G3 Ray
G4 Tim
```

and a second list in another file

```
Jack John
Tim Jack
```

I want to write a bash code that gives me a third file like this

```
G2 G1
G4 G2
```

EDIT
My solution is this, but nothing happens when I write it in bash.

```
#! /bin/bash
INPUTFILE="id.tsv"
DATAFILE="g.tsv"
OUTFILE="output.csv"

awk 'BEGIN {
while (getline < "'"$INPUTFILE"'")
{
split($0,ft,"\t");
id=ft[1];
name=ft[2];

key=id;
data=name;
nameArr[key]=data;
}
close("'"$INPUTFILE"'");

while (getline < "'"$DATAFILE"'")
{
split($0,ft,",");
id1=ft[1]; # Id is the first column
id2=ft[2]; # Phonenumber is the second
name1=nameArr[id1]; 
name2=nameArr[id2]; 
print name1","name2 > "'"$OUTFILE"'"; # Print directly to the outputfile
}
}'
```

Comment: Use awk. Make an array using the keys and values in the first file, then loop through all the fields in the second file and make the substitutions. Try that and let us know if you get stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2]=$1; next} {print a[$1], a[$2]}' file1 file2

G2 G1
G4 G2
```

Answer (score 1):

Karakfa's answer using awk is very concise, and for that reason, I'd probably prefer that method in my own scripts.

However, it's worth noting that you can do this directly in bash (version 4 and above) using an associative array:

```
declare -A map

while read -r line; do
  id="${line% *}"
  name="${line#* }"
  map["$name"]="$id"
done < file1

while read -r line; do
  ids=()
  for name in $line; do
    ids+=( "${map["$name"]}" )
  done
  echo "${ids[@]}"
done < file2
```

Output:

```
G2 G1
G4 G2
```

Keep in mind that this code is not portable. If portability is a concern, that's even more reason to use awk instead.